# Locate then Sort a single column

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, find

How would I finish this macro:?

```
Public Sub LocateSortGroupNumber()
Dim rngAddress As Range
Set rngAddress = Range("A1:BZ1").Find("Group Number")
If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Group Number column was not found"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Select    
End Sub
```

After selecting the range, i want to sort it descending. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Start by selecting all the code and tapping ctrl+K.

Comment: just [googling](https://www.google.it/search?q=vba+excel+range+sort&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=F2zCWquGHOrBXpn_uGA)

Comment: Record a macro of sorting the range.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a tip for future questions, I would advice you to phrase your question more precisely. 'Finishing this macro' is way too broad. 'How to sort a range in Excel using VBA is better. Or maybe even just 'How to sort a range' and using the Excel and VBA tags instead. As for a possible solution, try using the Macro recorder as @Mistella suggests. And then come back if you still haven't overcome your challenge.

Comment: I will definitely strive to take your feedback and convert on it in future questions. Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic VBA Sort a single column in descending order ignoring adjacent information.

```
Public Sub LocateSortGroupNumber()
    Dim rngAddress As Range
    Set rngAddress = Range("A1:BZ1").Find("Group Number")
    If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Group Number column was not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    with Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown))
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xldescending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    end with    
End Sub
```